# Keep sap.m.MultiComboBox permanently open even after selecting an option

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to keep [sap.m.MultiComboBox](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.MultiComboBox/preview) open by disabling the drop down toggle upon selecting a checkbox option or any other way of achieving the same.

Answer (score 1):

The MultiComboBox is design to close if the on of the items is clicked. If you check one of the checkboxes it will remain open and just a selection will be triggered.

You can also try to modify the autoclose with something like:

```
oMultiComboBox.getPicker().oPopup.setAutoClose(false)
```

But this is not a public API so it is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using a SelectList? I believe this emulates what you are trying to achieve

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.SelectList/preview

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to override the close method of MultiComboxBox. Below is the working code:

View:

```
<MultiComboBox selectionChange="handleSelectionChange" id='cb'   
  selectionFinish="handleSelectionFinish" width="500px"
        items="{/ProductCollection}">
        <core:Item key="{ProductId}" text="{Name}" />
    </MultiComboBox>
```

Controller:

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
        var cb = this.byId('cb');
        cb.open(); // Open the MultiCOmboxBox. Remove this if you want user to open this.
        cb.close = function (evt) {
          // dont do anything. Just return; Override default functionality.
        }
        // this makes sure that popup is not closed if clicked outside the popup
       cb.getAggregation('picker').oPopup._bAutoClose = false;

    },
```

Let me know if this works for you.